# 2021 Potential Community Moderator Election - Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, moderation

**Update**

We posted this to gauge interest, and, well, there wasn't enough interest at this time to justify holding an election. The CMs will check in with us every few months as we continue to grow, so when there is a need to hold an election we will be able to.

**-------------------------------------------**

It's time for us all to consider holding an election for a new volunteer moderator on Video Production.

[AJ Henderson](https://video.stackexchange.com/users/2836/aj-henderson), [PTS](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3295/pts) and I have been moderators since 2014, when the Sound and Video sites split out into their current structure, and although it's not a lot of work being a moderator on a relatively small SE site, we have grown significantly (our traffic is around 5 times that in 2014) and we came out of Beta status in 2019 along with a few other sites, so it's worth us checking regularly to see whether anyone would like to join us on the mod team.

You can also take a look at [Who are the site moderators, and what is their role here?](https://video.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) and the [Theory of moderation (revisited)](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) to get a bit of a feeling as to what being a moderator actually entails.

**Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election.**

NOTE: This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up.